# Grafico Primefaces com Consulta por Mês e Ano

Tags: java, primefaces, xhtml, jquery

Estou tentando fazer a consulta de um gráfico por mês e ano que quando eu clicar nas series do gráfico exibira os registros pertencente aquele caminho. Ao fazer a pesquisa o gráfico é montado corretamente conforme o mês e o ano selecionado, mas quando clico em alguma serie da um erro de *IndexOutOfBoudsException* index:28, size:18 por exemplo. Constatei que o 18 é da lista do mês atual(ao carregar a pagina o gráfico é montado sempre com o mês atual) e o 28 é a lista do da data que estou pesquisando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo onde a Serie é selecionada e abre um modal com os registros

```
public void caminhoSelecionado(ItemSelectEvent event) throws ParseException {
    modal = event.getItemIndex();

    String caminho = retornaTipoCaminho(modal, ano, mes);
    System.out.println("o que tem aqui  " + retornaTipoCaminho(modal, ano, mes));

    if (ano != null && mes != null) {
        listaModal = filtroBS.retornaCaminhoPorAno(caminho, ano, mes);
        System.out.println("o que caiu aqui? " + caminho);

    } else {
        listaModal.clear();
        listaModal = filtroBS.retornaCaminhoModal(caminho);
        System.out.println(" Tamanho " + listaModal.size());
    }
}
```

Código onde retorno uma Lista de Caminhos para o Gráfico.

```
public String retornaTipoCaminho(Integer codigo, String ano, Integer mes) throws ParseException {

    List<String> listaCaminhos = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (ChamadosEntity f : listaCategoria) {
        listaCaminhos.add(f.getCaminho());

    }
    return listaCaminhos.get(codigo).toString();
}
```

Código onde eu crio o gráfico a partir da pesquisa

```
public void pesquisaCaminhoData() throws ParseException {     
    if (ano != null && mes != null) {
        System.out.println("Tem lista aqui " + listaModal.size());

        createHorizontalBarModel(ano, mes);  
    } else {
        System.out.println("Erro está aqui ");
    }
}
```

E aqui meu xhtml.

```
<p:dialog modal="true" header="Pesquisar" widgetVar="dlg2" style="width: 500px; height: 800px" closable="true" responsive="true">
  <h:form id="FrmData">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group" style="text-align: center;">
      <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{graficoBarMB.mes}" class="fonte">
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Janeiro"  itemValue="0" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Fevereiro" itemValue="1" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Março" itemValue="2" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Abril" itemValue="3" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Maio" itemValue="4" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Junho" itemValue="5" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Julho" itemValue="6" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Agosto" itemValue="7" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Setembro" itemValue="8" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Outubro" itemValue="9" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Novembro" itemValue="10" />
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Dezembro" itemValue="11" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
      </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
          <p:selectOneMenu value="#{graficoBarMB.ano}" class="fonte">
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" />
              <f:selectItems value="#{graficoBarMB.listaAno}" />
              <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{graficoBarMB.anoSelecionado}"/>
          </p:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <p:commandButton value="Filtrar" action="#{graficoBarMB.pesquisaCaminhoData}" ajax="false" update="frmChart :frmChart:caminho" process="@all"  styleClass="green-btn">
            <f:param name="ano" value="#{graficoBarMB.anoT}" />                    
            <f:param name="mes" value="#{graficoBarMB.mes}" />
        </p:commandButton>
      </p:panelGrid>
  </h:form>
</p:dialog>
  <div class="botãofiltrar">
    <p:commandButton style="margin-top: 15px;" value="Filtrar" onclick="PF('dlg2').show()" styleClass="green-btn" />
  </div>
  <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="dlg1" style="width: 500px; height: 800px" closable="true" responsive="true">
    <p:tabView id="tblView" class="tabview"  cache="false" >
      <p:tab title="Chamados por Caminho">
        <p:dataTable id="tblModal" widgetVar="tblModal" var="caminho" value="#{graficoBarMB.listaModal}" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="577">
          <p:column headerText="Chamados" sortBy="#{caminho.chamado}" width="8%">
              <h:outputText value="#{caminho.chamado}"/>
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Titulo" filterBy="#{caminho.titulo}"  sortBy="#{caminho.titulo}" width="35%">
              <h:outputText value="#{caminho.titulo}"/>
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Clientes" filterBy="#{caminho.cliente}" sortBy="#{caminho.cliente}" width="28%">
              <h:outputText value="#{caminho.cliente}"/>
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Data Abertura" sortBy="#{caminho.dataAbertura}" style="height: 1px">
              <h:outputText value="#{caminho.dataAbertura}">
                  <f:convertDateTime  pattern=" dd/MM/Y H:mm  " locale="pt_BR" timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo" />
              </h:outputText>
          </p:column>
          <p:column headerText="Data Vencimento" sortBy="#{caminho.dataVencimento}" style="height: 1px">
              <h:outputText value="#{caminho.dataVencimento}">
                  <f:convertDateTime  pattern=" dd/MM/Y H:mm  " locale="pt_BR" timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo" />
              </h:outputText>
          </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
      </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
  </p:dialog>
  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-lg-12 "   onclick="PF('dlg1').show()"    >
    <h1 class="centerText">Grafico Teste</h1>
    <p:chart id="caminho" type="bar" model="#{graficoBarMB.horizontalBarModel}" responsive="true" class="Bargrafico" > 
      <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{graficoBarMB.caminhoSelecionado}" update="tblView:tblModal" />
    </p:chart>
  </div>
</h:form>
```

Gráfico:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bean:

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class GraficoBarMB implements Serializable {

```
private final FiltroBS filtroBS = new FiltroBS();
private final ConsultaBS consultaBS = new ConsultaBS();

private BarChartDAO barChartDAO;
private List<ChamadosEntity> graficoCaminho;
private List<ChamadosEntity> graficoDosCaminho;
private HorizontalBarChartModel horizontalBarModel = new HorizontalBarChartModel();
private Integer modal;
private List<ChamadosEntity> listaModal = new ArrayList<ChamadosEntity>();
private final List<ChamadosEntity> listaCategoria = consultaBS.retornaCaminho();
private List<Integer> listaAno = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private String ano;
private Integer mes;

@PostConstruct
public void init() throws ParseException {
    barChartDAO = new BarChartDAO();
    createHorizontalBarModel(ano, mes);
    carregaLista();
    listaAno = retornaAno();
}

/*
 ************************************************** 
 *** CARREGA A CONSULTA COM A LISTA DE CAMINHOS +++ 
 ************************************************** 
 */
public void carregaLista() {
    try {
        listaModal = filtroBS.retornaCaminhoModal("PDV » TECLADO");
    } catch (ParseException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 ******************************************** 
 *** CRIA UMA LISTA DE ANOS PARA PESQUISA +++ 
 ******************************************** 
 */
private List<Integer> retornaAno() {

    Integer i = 0;
    Integer inicio = 2015;
    Integer calculo = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        calculo = inicio + i;
        listaAno.add(calculo);
    }
    return listaAno;
}

/*
 ******************************* 
 *** GET DO HORIZONTAL CHART +++ 
 ******************************* 
 */
public HorizontalBarChartModel getHorizontalBarModel() {
    return horizontalBarModel;
}

/*
 ******************************************** 
 *** INICIA GRAFICO A PARTIR DO MES E ANO +++ 
 ******************************************** 
 */
private HorizontalBarChartModel initHorizontalBarChartModel(String ano, Integer mes) throws ParseException {

    graficoCaminho = new ArrayList<ChamadosEntity>();

    HorizontalBarChartModel model = new HorizontalBarChartModel();

    if (ano != null && mes != null) {

        graficoCaminho = filtroBS.retornaCaminhoPesquisado(ano, mes);

        System.out.println("CAIU NO FILTRO DO GRAFICO!!!!!!!!!!!!");

    } else {

        graficoCaminho = barChartDAO.listaCaminho();

    }

    ChartSeries barras = new ChartSeries();

    for (ChamadosEntity cm : graficoCaminho) {
        barras.set(cm.getCaminho(), cm.getChamados());

    }

    model.addSeries(barras);
    return model;
}

/*
 ***************************** 
 *** MONTA GRAFICO NA TELA +++ 
 ***************************** 
 */
private void createHorizontalBarModel(String ano, Integer mes) throws ParseException {

    horizontalBarModel = initHorizontalBarChartModel(ano, mes);
    horizontalBarModel.setTitle("Horizontal and Stacked");
    horizontalBarModel.setLegendPosition("e");
    horizontalBarModel.setStacked(true);
    horizontalBarModel.setShowPointLabels(true);

    Axis xAxis = horizontalBarModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);
    xAxis.setLabel("Quantidade de Chamados");
    xAxis.setMin(0);
    xAxis.setMax(100);
    xAxis.setTickFormat("%1$.0f");

    Axis yAxis = horizontalBarModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setLabel("Caminhos");
}

/*
 ******************************** 
 *** EXIBE MODAL COM CHAMADOS +++ 
 ******************************** 
 */
public void caminhoSelecionado(ItemSelectEvent event) throws ParseException {
    modal = event.getItemIndex();

    String caminho = retornaTipoCaminho(modal);
    System.out.println("o que tem aqui  " + retornaTipoCaminho(modal));

    if (ano != null && mes != null) {
        listaModal = filtroBS.retornaCaminhoPorAno(caminho, ano, mes);
        System.out.println("o que caiu aqui? " + caminho);

    } else {
        listaModal.clear();
        listaModal = filtroBS.retornaCaminhoModal(caminho);
        System.out.println(" Tamanho " + listaModal.size());
    }
}

/*
 ***************************************** 
 *** RETORNA UMA LISTA COM OS CAMINHOS +++ 
 *****************************************
 */
public String retornaTipoCaminho(Integer codigo) throws ParseException {

    List<String> listaCaminhos = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (ChamadosEntity f : listaCategoria) {
        listaCaminhos.add(f.getCaminho());
        //System.out.println("lista de caminhos " + listaCaminhos);

    }
    System.out.println(" Qual o tamanho da lista de caminhos " + listaCaminhos.size());
    return listaCaminhos.get(codigo).toString();
}


/*
 **************************************************************** 
 *** MONTA O GRAFICO PELA PESQUISA +++ 
 ****************************************************************
 */
public void pesquisaCaminhoData() throws ParseException {

    System.out.println("ANO: " + ano);
    System.out.println("MES: " + mes);

    if (ano != null && mes != null) {

        System.out.println("Tem lista aqui " + listaModal.size());

        createHorizontalBarModel(ano, mes);

        listaModal.clear();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Erro está aqui ");
    }

}
```

Comment: essa exception é lançada nessa linha `    return listaCaminhos.get(codigo).toString();`?

Comment: Sim, é lançando nesta linha.

Comment: primeira dúvida, por que você passa `, String ano, Integer mes` no método retornaTipoCaminho, se você não utiliza?

Comment: e, você tem certeza que listaCategoria é a lista que você precisa pra resolver o seu problema?

Comment: Por que, o que que acontece é que você tá tentando acessar uma posição que não existe no array listaCaminhos, que foi montado a partir de listaCategoria. Então listaCategoria não deve ter, se quer, o tamaho do `codigo` que foi passado

Comment: Entendi,  está pegando sempre o tamanho da lista do mês atual, então quando eu tento pesquisar meses anteriores que podem ter caminhos a mais ou menos que está caindo nessa exception.

Comment: quando clico em algum caminho no gráfico do mês atual,  percorre a lista duas vezes trazendo os dezoito caminhos do mês, quando eu realizo a pesquisa e clico em algum caminho percorre a lista uma vez trazendo 18 e não a quantidade do mês atual

Comment: não entendi, resolveu o problema?
o que seria o caminho do gráfico? não tenho conhecimento de como é o gráfico e de como é montado, ai não dá pra entender

Comment: Ainda não, adicionei uma foto do gráfico, ele está dando um update e limpado mês e ano quando tento trazer resultados clicando nos caminhos.

Comment: qual o espoco do seu managed bean?

Comment: ViewScoped.....

Comment: de `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` ?

Comment: Sim, este mesmo.

Comment: ta difícil de entender o problema, eu sei que a exception é lançada pelo fato de listaCaminhos não ter o elemento na posição 18(nesse exemplo) e que listaCaminhos é construída a partir de listaCategoria. Faz o seguinte, debuga e verifica se listaCategoria está com os dados que você precisa.

Comment: A listaCategoria traz os caminhos corretamente, fiz uma coisa aqui passei o ano = "2016" e o mês = 5, e ele trouxe exatamente o que eu queria, quer dizer que ele está perdendo o mês e o ano quando a pagina está sendo limpada para a criação do gráfico a partir da pesquisa, tentei usar uma variável mesmo assim ele perde, também tentei criar um entity com ano e mês e ele da erro de campo null.

Comment: coloca todo o seu bean e descreve o processo

Comment: coloquei, cara está ficando muito extenso aqui, não quer mover para o chat?

Comment: pode ser, chama lá no chat.

Comment: poucos pontos de reputação, nem consigo chamar. no carregaLista() uso para carregar uma lista de chamados para usar no evento clique nas barras do gráfico, retornaAno() crio uma serie de anos para usar na pesquisa, no initHorizontalBarChartModel() inicio o gráfico a partir do mês e ano. no caminho selecionado pego a lista que carrega os chamados e uso ela para quando eu clicar na barra ele exibir um modal com os chamados correspondentes  aquele caminho no pesquisacaminhodata() é onde eu crio o gráfico quando efetuo a pesquisa

Comment: Só preciso de um jeito que essas variáveis ano e mês fiquem armazenadas, tentei varias coisas só que elas são limpas todas a vezes

Comment: lendo seu código aqui, você está "atualizando" a variável `ano` e `mês` em um método e passando as duas variáveis `ano` e `mês` por parâmetro. Só que quando você passa uma String como parâmetro, você não passa uma referência pra variável que você está passando, ou seja, ele cria outra string. Então, se você atualizar, nada vai importar, pois o escopo vai ser apenas no método.

Comment: Você pode fazer o seguinte. Criar uma classe pra representar esse mês e ano. ex: `public class FiltroCaminho{private String ano; private String mes; getters e setters}` e ao invés de passar como parâmetro `...( ano,  mes)...` você passa `...(filtroCaminho)...` e suas strings de ano e mês serão atualizadas

Comment: Blz, vou fazer aqui.

Comment: Deu certo @HenriqueSantiago consegui armazenar desse jeito que você falou. Obrigado!

Comment: Pra eu marcar como resolvido você tem que colocar como resposta certo?

Comment: show. Vou fazer uma resposta, posto, aí você aceita. (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema era com o escopo das variáveis `mes`e `ano` que você tentava atualizar em algum método e não tinha êxito.

Você pode fazer o seguinte. Criar uma classe pra representar esse mês e ano.

ex:

```
public class FiltroCaminho{
    private String ano; 
    private String mes; 

    //getters e setters
}
```

e ao invés de passar como parâmetro ...( ano, mes)... você passa ...(filtroCaminho)... e suas strings de ano e mês serão atualizadas.